# How i can use WPS in raspberry pi 3b

Tags: wifi

I am using rapbian for my raspberry 3b+.
I need headless wifi configuration for my system
But, wps not working.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What have you tried? Did you see any error messages?

Comment: Have you installed WPS? Why it is not working? What error messages do you get? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wi-Fi Setup Raspberry Pi 3 with WPS (Wi-Fi Protected Setup) not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43681/wi-fi-setup-raspberry-pi-3-with-wps-wi-fi-protected-setup-not-working)

Comment: Also consider that WPS is broken to the point where you might as well set up an open WiFi network. At least you won't have a false sense of security.